# Infopath form data to a remote SQL Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, infopath

We have data in a SQL Server database hosted remotely.

Can I set up Infopath forms so that the data lands in our remote SQL Server instance instead of on the local Microsoft server where the employees get their Outlook mail?

We don't run  Sharepoint, just Exchange and file sharing on the Windows server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention what version of Infopath you have.

With Infopath 2007, you can create a form template that queries and submits data to SQL Server 2000 and 2005.

On the **Design a Form Template** window, just select **Database**, then the **Data Connection Wizard** starts and it should be pretty self explanatory from there.